# How to remove plugin metaboxes from edit.php

Tags: plugins, filters, metabox

I want to remove some metaboxes, that was added to page edit.php by thridparty plugins. I insert this code into functions.php:

```
function vpm_remove_meta_box() {
        remove_meta_box( 'ortext-metabox', 'post', 'normal' );
        remove_meta_box( 'ez-toc', 'post', 'normal' );
}
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'vpm_remove_meta_box' );
```

But, it don't working. I found that plugins register this metaboxes with function:

```
add_meta_box('ortext-metabox', OrTextBase::NAME_SERVIC_ORIGINAL_TEXT, array($this, 'metabosHtml'), "$v", 'side', 'high');
add_meta_box( 'ez-toc', esc_html__( 'Table of Contents', 'ez-toc' ), array( $this, 'displayMetabox' ) );
```

How i can get it done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `do_meta_boxes` hook to remove the metaboxes instead.

Like below

```
add_action( 'do_meta_boxes', 'vpm_remove_meta_box' );
function vpm_remove_meta_box() {
    remove_meta_box( 'ortext-metabox', 'post', 'normal' );
    remove_meta_box( 'ez-toc', 'post', 'normal' );
}
```

See this for more info

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/remove_meta_box/

Comment: Thanks, but it do not working too. I heared, that hock admin_menu executes too early for plugins.

Comment: Sorry about that ! I have updated the code and the wrong link. Looks like `do_meta_boxes` is the way to go

Comment: Did this work ?

Comment: No, it didn't work.